# Is there a downside to leaving matches early?

Tags: mortal-kombat-x

I have noticed that, if I have already lost, it is faster to quit a match and queue for a new one than to wait for my opponent to optionally perform a fatality, then do his victory pose, then wait for both of us to acknowledge the winner, then requeue.

I don't really care to see all these fatalities ad infinitum. When I win, I use the fastest attack possible to end the round. Others cannot be relied on for the same courtesy, so I'm just trying to get back in game faster.

Is there some downside to quitting when you have already lost, other than possibly seeming like a bad sport?

Comment: Aren't fatalities like half the point?

Comment: @GnomeSlice I knew that comment was from you before I even read it. No. Fatalities are boring and waste tons of time.

Comment: @StrixVaria Finish him!

Comment: I'm sure if your goal is to watch fatalities YouTube will serve the purpose better and not waste someone else's time.

Comment: @Nelson Yes, which is why it's so annoying that like 75% or more of my opponents do fatalities when they win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving a match mid-game will count as a loss on your profile. There is no other penalty such as "low priority queue" in other games, or only being matched with other quitters.

The only possible downside to leaving matches early is you may have missed a chance to make a comeback and you miss the fatalities at the end.

Comment: Missing fatalities is a bonus if anything.